# Force URL to open in tab in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, infragistics, webdatagrid

I have a link in my webdatagrid as follows:

I open the link using following:

         var PageURL = "XYZ.aspx?XYZID=" + rows.get_cell(8).get_value();
                window.open(PageURL, "", "menubar=1,resizable=1,location=1,scrollbars=1");

Now my problem is that, it works perfectly fine when the settings of IE& is 

"When popup encountered:>>> Always open pop-ups in a new window and Always open pop-ups in a new tab

but when the setting is "Let Internet Explorer decide how pop-ups should open" it creates a problem and it opens in a new window and that window has lot of issues.

Please help me to force URL to open in new tab only.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. This can only be controlled in the browser and not by the website.

**Detail:**

You (webdeveloper) can specify if a link should open in a `new window`. The visitor can specify if a `new window` should open in a new `browser window` or in a `new tab`.

Comment: I got the solution:


var PageURL = "XYZ.aspx?XYZID=" + rows.get_cell(8).get_value(); window.open(PageURL, "", "menubar=1,resizable=1,location=1,scrollbars=1"); 


If I remove the parameters then it worked perfectly fine for the option:
Let Internet Explorer decide how pop-ups should open



var PageURL = "XYZ.aspx?XYZID=" + rows.get_cell(8).get_value(); window.open(PageURL, "", "");